# js if any value in array is under or over value

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

say you have (any amount) values in an array and you want to see if any of them is over (lower amount) and under higher amount, how would you do that?

answer without doing a for loop or any lengthy code.

Maybe something like:

```
var havingParty = false;
if ((theArrayWithValuesIn > 10) && (theArrayWithValuesIn < 100)) {
    havingParty = true;
} else {
    havingParty = false;
}
```

would work.

Please note: `x` and `y`, collision detection, compact code.

Comment: And whats wrong with this code? You want to get all values betwen these numbers? Why a loop no good?

Comment: @lolka_bolka because i already have enough for loops and it could be an array of numbers or a single number that isn't in an array. do you get what i mean

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check if a given array has any value greater than some other value.

There is a useful function for this called `some` ([Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some))

An example of using this would be:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a.some(el => el > 5) // false, since no element is greater than 5
a.some(el => el > 4) // true, since 5 is greater than 4
a.some(el => el > 3) // true, since 4 and 5 are greater than 3
```

A similar function to this is `every`, which checks if all the values fulfil a given condition ([Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)).

An example of this would be:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a.every(el => el > 3) // false
a.every(el => el > 0) // true
```

My examples simply check for greater than, but you could pass in any callback that returns a boolean value for more complicated checks.

So for your example, something like this might do the trick if you want to check that all the elements fill the requirement:

```
const havingParty = theArrayWithValuesIn.every(el => el < 100 && el > 10);
```

or

```
const havingParty = theArrayWithValuesIn.some(el => el < 100 && el > 10);
```

if you you only care that at least one element fills the requirement.

Comment: so, is some like an any while every is like an all?

Comment: also, how does `value < other value` when not in an if work? is it like how setting a value to a literal string works? is an expression a literal?

Comment: Exactly, `some` translates to `any` in other programming languages, and `every` is basically `all`. I'm afraid I don't understand your second question.

Comment: does english count as a programming language?

Comment: I suppose not, you got me there. I was simply trying to point out that the method names are not consistent across programming languages.

Comment: I'm about to try it and see if any errors occur. wish me luck!

Comment: heh, good to look back, i now use dartlang and it uses any, much better wording.

Comment: And now i'm looking back at this, i still use dartlang, and this whole thing is just a simple `list.any((x) => x > 10 && x < 100)`, geez i was 11 when i asked this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple answer :

```
var arr = [0,10,100,30,99];
var config = {min:0,max:100};

// filter is a method that returns only array items that respect a 
//condition(COND1 in this case )
var arr2 = arr.filter(function(item){
  //COND 1 : 
  return item > config.min && item < config.max;
});
```

Comment: please add comments to the code so i understand it and can adapt it to my needs

Comment: Just as an addition: if you only want to know if an element exists that fulfills the condition, you could check the length of arr2 like: `var exists = arr2.length > 0`

Answer (score 0):

According to your condition

> "if any of them is over (lower amount) and under higher amount"

`Array.some` function will be the most suitable "tool":

```
var min = 10, max = 100,
    result1 = [1, 2, 3, 30].some((v) => min < v && v < max),
    result2 = [1, 2, 3, 10].some((v) => min < v && v < max);

console.log(result1);  // true
console.log(result2);  // false
```