# Get array values in a range

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of values, in this case its timestamps.

For example,

[1562460093000, 1562581818000, 1562581818000, 1562582266000, 1562760409000,
1562760409000 ...]

Before adding it to the array, I would like to compare a new value (call it x) to the values already existing within in the array and if it matches or is within a minute either side(-60000 and +60000) then x does not get added to the array, if there is no value within that range then x is added to the array.

This code is situated within a for loop where x will be a different value on each loop.

This is what I have attempted so far:

```
var minusMinute = x - 60000;
var plusMinute = x + 60000;
var last24hours = [];

if(last24hours.indexOf(x >= minusMinute && x <= plusMinute) == -1){
    last24hours.push(x);
}
```

However this doesn't seem to work as I still have values within those ranges being added to the array.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [js if any value in array is under or over value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373225/js-if-any-value-in-array-is-under-or-over-value)

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf()` doesn't take condition as argument it just takes the element and get its index. In case you need to check for some condition for all element use `some()` or `every()`

```
if(last24hours.every(x =>  x >= minusMinute && x <= plusMinute)){
    last24hours.push(x);
}
```

Comment: I believe you missed a closing ) somewhere, where should it be?

Comment: @AlexMorrison Fixed that. Thanks

Comment: I think some() is the method I need because if only 1 of the values already in the array is within a minute of x, then x should not be pushed into the array. However, when I run the code from scratch the array is still empty

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the value not the index:

```
var push = true ;
for (let i = 0 ; i < last24hours.length ; i ++ ){
   var difference_minute = Math.abs (x - last24hours[i]);
   if (difference_minute <60000){
    push = false ;
    break;
   }
}

if (push){
   last24hours.push(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do both checks separately like

```
if(last24hours.indexOf(x) < 0 && (x < minusMinute || x > plusMinute)){
    last24hours.push(x);
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
last24hours.indexOf(x) < 0
```

This logic checks for that the value `x` is not already in the array using the [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method. Next:

```
(x < minusMinute || x > plusMinute)
```

checks for `x` is not within this range (-60000 and +60000) and finally, we use `&&` operator so that item is inserted only if both the conditions are satisfied.

Demo:

```js
var minusMinute = -60000;
var plusMinute = 60000;
var last24hours = [];

[-60002, -50000, 50000, 60002, -60002].forEach(x => {
  if (last24hours.indexOf(x) < 0 && (x < minusMinute || x > plusMinute)) {
    last24hours.push(x);
  }
})

console.log( last24hours )
```

Comment: To my understanding the second condition can never be met because the minusMinute and plusMinute values are generated from the inital x value, therefore x will never been less than minusMinute and it will never be greater than plusMinute. This means no value would ever be pushed into the array

Comment: Then we can simply hardcode those values and then it should work fine.

Comment: The x variable is a dynamic variable, so the value of it will be constantly different. Sorry, maybe should have included that in the inital question

Comment: I have added a demo above. It is working fine with dynamic `x` variable.